# Line coloring on link force d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am new on D3.js, and I already have create a graph force and it is working.
My doubt is about the coloring the link between two nodes.

I need represent the traffic using colors on link between nodes. 
But the problem is that the two nodes are sending trafic on link, and to represent this, I need two color for on the same link.
On case 50% of the link with one color and other 50% with other color.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want to represent each source->target link as a separate link so traffic from X to Y is a different link than traffic from Y to X. In that case, the typical method is to use curved edges, as seen in this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

You can also offset the link start and end points if you want to use straight edges that appear to be side-by-side but this is more involved because you have to have a way of telling the code which link is on the "left-hand" side and which is on the "right-hand" side. One way to do that is to use JavaScript's built-in Math.atan2 function to find the slope of the link and offset outbound links based on that slope. I'll try to write up an example when I get a chance.